# RavenDB sorting by Range field

Tags: ravendb

I've been playing around with the RavenDB Northwind database, and am having trouble getting orders sorted by Freight.

My index:

```
    Map = orders => from o in orders
                    select new {
                            o.Freight
                        };
    IndexSortOptions.Add(x => x.Freight, SortOptions.Double);
    Indexes.Add(x => x.Freight, FieldIndexing.NotAnalyzed);
```

My query:

```
 return sess.Query<Order>("Orders/ByFreight")
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Freight)
                    .Select(x => x.Freight);
```

It get the following order back:

```
[
    32.38,
    11.61,
    65.83,
    41.34 ... ]
```

Which is clearly not correct. In the studio, I can define the order to be by Freight, and it orders just fine. However, if in the studio I specify the range as over Freight_Range, I get these same results back. It appears to me that Raven is selecting the Freight_Range field to sort by rather than the Freight field. Why?

Answer (score 1):

- Remove the line starting with `Indexes.Add`.  You don't need to do that.
- Use this syntax instead of the `IndexSortOptions`:

  ```
  Sort(x=> x.Freight, SortOptions.Double);
  ```
- Make sure your `Freight` field is indeed a double as defined on your `Order` class.